# Ubuntu 20.4 virtualbox Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

Tags: drivers, kernel, virtualbox

> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please reinstall virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing'modprobe vboxdrv'
> as root.If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908)  - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

I tried certain commands like

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```

showing this error

```
Could not insert 'vboxdrv': Operation not permitted
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is Secure Boot disabled?

Comment: My secure boot is enabled , i want to stay with that way

Answer (score -2):

Am having the same issue over here, upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 and am having trouble with virtual box, it says the same thing as the original post says

Comment: This is not an answer. You should post this as a comment.